# How can I work with HEIC image files in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, heic

Is there a way to handle .heic image files in Python 2.7? For example, converting it to a jpg. Ideally with metadata, but could be OK without.

PIL/Pillow doesn't handle it natively. [Pyheif](https://pypi.org/project/pyheif/) requires Python 3.6+. (And, no, converting all our code to Python 3 is not a realistic solution right now.)

Comment: Pyheif can save images as JPEG. Would you be amenable to running a Python 3 script that does that, in preparation for your main code? You could even make it a command line utility and run it with `subprocess` from your main code.

Comment: (Having simultaneous Python 2 and 3 installations is usually pretty doable, depending on your platform, and it could be a good first step toward eventually transitioning. Python 2 is almost two years out of being supported, after all.)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu with Pyenv so having multiple installations would be doable. Call one from the other.